# Error Pgadmin III Server doesn't listen

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Acabo de instalar Pgadmin 3 (porque el 4 me lanza errores) entonces a la hora de crear un nuevo servidor me lanza el siguiente error:

> Server doesn't listen The server doesn't accept connections: the
>   connection library reports  could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect
>   to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running
>   on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432?

He investigado y algunas soluciones son entrar al administrador de tareas y buscar el servicio de Postgresql pero no aparece, pienso que ese es el problema, que el servicio ni siquiera ha iniciado, o no se que dicen ustedes. Tambien he buscado aquí mismo en el foro pero los casos ya publicados no se adaptan al mío. Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: La pregunta así es muy amplia: te quieres conectar a un gestor de BS PostgreSQL que está... ¿apagado?, ¿en local o en otra máquina? ¿Has probado a conectarte con el comando `psql`?

Comment: @PabloLozano Disculpa es que es mi primera vez que utilizo este gestor de base de datos, tambien primera vez que voy a trabajar con Postgresql, mis conocimientos son nulos.

Comment: Puede que tengas otra instancia de postgres instalada y es por eso que la nueva instalación te rechaza la conexión. Te recomendaría (si es posible) eliminar completamente cualquier instalación de postgres que tengas y chequear los puertos que tienes ocupados a través de la consola/terminal

Comment: Si por algún motivo no estás en local esto podría servirte: [unable to connect in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532399/unable-to-connect-to-server-for-postgres)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede que tu puerto 5432 esté ocupado por otro programa. Para garantizar que esto no es así, chequeamos mediante la ejecución en `cmd` (consola) del siguiente comando:

```
netstat -an | find ":5432"
```

Si la consola retorna información quiere decir que el puerto si está ocupado, si no retorna nada significa que está disponible para ser utilizado por cualquier programa.

> Te recomendaría (en lo posible) eliminar cualquier versión de
>   postgresql que tengas instalada en vista de que no hay garantía que la
>   instalación de pgadmin 4 se realizó correctamente y puede que esté
>   obstaculizando la correcta ejecución del pgadmin 3 y por ello obtienes
>   el error que habla sobre el puerto rechazando la conexión.

Existen muchas herramientas para eliminar programas "completamente" como **Revo Uninstaller** o **Ccleaner**. Te recomendaría utilizar **Revo Uninstaller** para eliminar las versiones de postgresql y luego ejecutar el limpiador de registros de **Ccleaner** tantas veces como sea necesario hasta que no aparezcan incidencias en el analizador.

**Observación:** Si quieres tener un sólo programa podrías utilizar Ccleaner tanto para desinstalar los programas como para limpiar el registro.

Reinicias el computador y pasas nuevamente el limpiador de registro del Ccleaner tantas veces como sea necesario.

Luego para eliminar el servicio de postgresql utilizas en tu consola de comandos con permisos de administrador:

```
net user /delete postgres
```

Para garantizar que no queda ningún "residuo" chequeas los servicios del sistema. Para ello te diriges a Inicio -> Ejecutar y colocas dentro de ejecutar `msconfig`.

Una vez en la ventana de configuración del sistema te diriges a la pestaña **servicios** y buscas (presionando la tecla <kbd>P</kbd> repetidamente) algún servicio de postgresql. Si encuentras aún a postgresql debes eliminar el servicio.

Luego procedes a instalar nuevamente la versión de postgresql que necesitas. Debes estar atento que no arroje ningún error la instalación porque aún cuando pueda completarse arrojando algún error no es recomendable precisamente porque se dan casos como el que estás presentando en este momento.

Al finalizar la instalación ve a inicio -> ejecutar y colocas `services.msc`. Cuando abra la ventana buscas otra vez presionando la tecla <kbd>p</kbd> hasta que ubiques el servicio de postgres. Una vez lo encuentres da doble click sobre él y revisa en que estatus se encuentra.

Si el servicio no está en funcionamiento debes intentar iniciarlo presionando en el botón de ***iniciar***. A estas alturas ya debería funcionar correctamente postgresql y por ende pgadmin. Sin cerrar esta ventana, ubica en Tipo de inicio la opción ***Automático*** y seleccionala. Con lo anterior logras que el servicio se ejecute automáticamente al encender el computador y automatizas la tarea.

A continuación algunas referencias que puedes seguir para ampliar información:

**1)** [Chequear puerto ocupado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817500/how-to-make-sure-that-a-certain-port-is-not-occupied-by-any-other-process)

**2)** [Iniciar automáticamente el servicio de postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475399/server-doesnt-listen-in-pgadmin-iii-with-postgresql)

**3)** [Instalar ccleaner](http://www.manualpc.com/como-instalar-ccleaner-en-pc/)

**4)** [Limpiar registro con ccleaner](https://serglobin.es/blog/informatica/tutorial-para-limpiar-y-optimizar-tu-ordenador-con-ccleaner/)

**5)** [Eliminar servicio en Windows](https://www.webespacio.com/eliminar-servicio-windows-en-windows-7/)

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: Excelente explicacion, ojala todas las respuestas para novatos fueran de ese estilo. el detalle inmejorable.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 Me alegra mucho que te ha servido. Gracias por tomar el tiempo para agradecer el aporte y me disculpo por reponder un poco tarde. Saludos!